# Asking for help about tensorflow " models mobilenet_v1_0.5_128 " / " mobilenet_v1_1.0_224 "

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow-model-analysis

I want to train my custom model using the pretained model " mobilenet_v1_0.5_128 " / " mobilenet_v1_1.0_224 " from tensorflow downloaded at: [download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_08_02/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tgz](http://download.tensorflow.org/models/mobilenet_v1_2018_08_02/mobilenet_v1_1.0_224.tgz) which will make it easier for me to convert it to .tflite later

Where can I find the right config file matched to those models (or to one of them)? Because when I use some config files from the tensorflow official github repository, when launching the training I got the following error:

> ValueError: No variables to save

I'm sure the problem is because I don't use the correct config file.

Comment: Please do your best to write the question clear, in such way that the question is now it's very hard to help you

Comment: Thank you.

My problem is that I want to find the right config file matched to these tensorflow models **"mobilenet_v1_0.5_128" / "mobilenet_v1_1.0_224"** so that I can use them to train my custom model

Comment: Assuming you are trying to use the file `mobilenet_v1_1.0_224_frozen.pb` from the zip you have referenced, it means you are trying to use a frozen graph. A frozen graph is a model in which all the Variables have been converted to Const ops using [freeze_graph.py](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph.py). So the error that you are getting means that the model you are trying to work with has no Variables because it has previously been frozen. It would be helpful if you provide the exact config file and commands you are running.

Comment: Thanks, a user from the tensorflow team on github helped me figure it out, but now I want to see the graph the graph details (nodes...)

python tensorflow/python/tools/import_pb_to_tensorboard.py --model_dir resnetv1_50.pb --log_dir /tmp/tensorboard command found on: [link](https://developer.arm.com/technologies/machine-learning-on-arm/developer-material/how-to-guides/optimizing-neural-networks-for-mobile-and-embedded-devices-with-tensorflow/determine-the-names-of-input-and-output-nodes) seems not to be helpful